# Loop through form input-elements filtered by more than one element type with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I have a jQuery function that loops over a form:

```
var id = 'doesnt-matter';

$('#element_'+id+' input:[type!=hidden]').each(function () {
  // do stuff
});
```

I want to exclude hidden fields and radio buttons. I tried to do something like

```
$('#element_'+id+' input:[type!=hidden, type!=radio]').each(function () {
  // do stuff
});
```

but this doesn't work. Is it possible to do this at all or do I need to check inside the loop for the input:type instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#element_'+id+' input').not("[type=hidden],[type=radio]").each(function () {
 // do stuff
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#element_'+id+' input[type!="hidden"][type!="radio"]').each(function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

See:
[Multiple attribute selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) 
[Attribute not equal selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

Comment: @Barmar But `.not()` is much faster than not equal attribute selector.

Comment: In that case I'll undelete. The OP will have to flip a coin to choose between our answers that were posted almost simultaneously.

Comment: Tuff one to decide, but I do like the .not solution better. +1 for nbrooks for posting the links though. 
Thanks guys. I knew it was doable but it's hard to search for syntax related questions sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not` method.

```
$('#element_'+id+' input').not('[type=hidden], [type=radio]').each(function() {
       // do stuff
});
```